# Beginner What is asterisk stands for on local address

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I am new to ubuntu server as well as server too.

When I am checking the open port using command 'netstat' .On the column of local address, there is *.http and *:ssh

what does * meaning of?

Comment: Did you mean "*:http" (a colon instead of a period)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that services http and ssh are listening on all addresses available on your server.

This means at least listening on localhost (127.0.0.1) and probably on the LAN address (eg: 10.x.x.x or 192.168.x.x).

Answer (score 0):

The asterix indicates that the service is listening for traffic on ALL available addresses.

Localhost and the machines defined ip-address.
If the system has multiple ip-interfaces (and thus multiple ip-addresses), all of those are included.

If a service is only bound to a specific ip-address you will see that listed here by address.

Please note this also includes services listing for multicast addresses. (So you will see 224.0.0.* appear as an ip-address in some cases.)